# How to add three paragraphs in one line using wordprocessing document c#

Tags: c#

I have a word document where I add three paragraphs. I want to add three paragraphs in one line not like is displaying now in different lines like this:
text1
text2
text3.
I want to be text1,text2,text3.

Here is my code:

```
using(WordprocessingDocument wDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(ms, true))
{
    gjenerimi = randomstring(14);
    var body = wDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
    var lastParagraf = body.Elements < Paragraph > ().FirstOrDefault();

    var newParagraf2 = new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(DateTime.Now.ToString())));
    var newParagraf3 = new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(gjenerimi)));
    var newParagraf4 = new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(merreshifren())));

    lastParagraf.InsertAfterSelf(newParagraf2);
    lastParagraf.InsertAfterSelf(newParagraf3);
    lastParagraf.InsertAfterSelf(newParagraf4);
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Why don't you concatenate the text beforehand, like using a stringbuffer? and pass it on as a single paragraph? because you are explicitly creating three different paragraphs in your code as it stands.

Comment: One line of code, one command. That is the clearest approach. Wanting to execute multiple commands in a single line is impossible in some cases, and bad practice in other cases. There's no functional nor technical reason to want to do so. If you're looking to iteratively approach this, look into using Linq or a simple `foreach`/`for`/`while` loop.

Comment: I have two call three methods in each paragraph and I don't know how to make them display in one row.

Comment: @ArbenitaMusliu You need to look up the definition of **[paragraph](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paragraph)**: _a subdivision of a written composition that consists of one or more sentences, deals with one point or gives the words of one speaker, **and begins on a new usually indented line**_. If you make three paragraphs, you will logically get three separate text blocks.

Comment: A "paragraph" usually is a single block of text. So if you want your three texts to form "one line" (which I read as: one paragraph), you should probably add just one Paragraph, probably containing 3 Runs

Comment: I tried like that:  var newParagraf2 = new Paragraph(

                               new Run(new Text( DateTime.Now.ToString()))
                                   new Run(new Text(gjenerimi))
                                    new Run(new Text(merreshifren()))); is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want paragraphs, don't use paragraphs:

```
using(WordprocessingDocument wDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(ms, true))
{
    var gjenerimi = randomstring(14);

    var body = wDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

    var lastParagraf = body.Elements<Paragraph>().FirstOrDefault();

    var run = new Run();

    run.AppendChild(new Text(DateTime.Now.ToString()));
    run.AppendChild(new Text(gjenerimi));
    run.AppendChild(new Text(merreshifren()));

    lastParagraf.AppendChild(run);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.It is working. Do you know is there any possibility to put that paragraph on the footer in one page before the last one?

Comment: I think header and footer cannot be set per page. I do remember even/odd pages, but you cannot just set a footer for a specific page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Do you know can we decrees the font size of the paragraph using wordprocessing dokument??

Comment: You set the FontSize in the RunProperties. You can easily google it.